# Trying to delete values in an hdf5 file with PyTables, but file size is not shrinking

Tags: python, pytables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing data from a HDF5 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124994/removing-data-from-a-hdf5-file)

I have an hdf5 file, which contains a group structure like:

```
-->"Databases"  
    --> "Some name of some db"
       --> Some field
          --> Table 1
             --> Table 2
             --> Table 3
       --> Some other field
             --> Table 1
             --> Table 2
```

I would like to iterate through this, and delete "Some other field". I achieve this by the line

> h5file.removeNode(db, field_name, recursive=True)
>   where db is the object for "Some name of some db" and the field name is the string "Some other field".

When I flush and save, the group is now removed (yay!), but the file size is the same (boo!). In this case my file size was 1.2Gb to begin with, and I removed the groups containing about 95% of the data (I kept only 1 of about 20 "fields").

Am I missing something? Is a group somehow just metadata, and the underlying array data still somehow there? How to do I go through and make a smaller file, containing only the information I need?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: I had a similar situation with another file some time ago. The solution for me was to completely re-create the file (read and create new). :-/